# Apple's APN Delivery acknowledgment

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, apn

Is there a way to find or confirm a Push notification (Apple Push Notification - APN) has really reached IOS Device? We are finding it hard to troubleshoot, when we get a success and a user complains that they haven't received the notification.

Comment: APN does not have a delivery guarantee. Push Notifications do get lost from time to time.

Comment: there is not feedback about (un)successful delivery – the concept is: you just _push_ it towards the desired direction and leave it.

Comment: Thanks Holex and Gereon.  I checked APN documentation. Didnt find any.